# wp7 smartlist search

Tags: windows-phone-7, controls

Is there a SmartList control for WP7, so as the user types if narrows down what is in the list for selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoCompleteBox, present in the Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit available at http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CollectionViewSource similar to this post: http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2011/2/13/wp7-in-app-searching-filtering-part-ii.html